# Tool Tip Complications in RadHtmlChart

Tags: telerik, radhtmlchart

I had query regarding the Tool tip display in RadHtmlChart.I wanted to display 4 things on tooltip if my condtion of dropdown is All else it should show only single value.

For example, A user has 4 types of call i.e SMS,MMS,Voice,DataCharges on which they accounted for. My dropdown has 4 values(Data,voice,SMS,MMS,All).In All condition of dropdown it should display different multiline ToolTip else it should just display column value respectively.

And if the value contains 0 then multiline tooltip should specify that it is zero.For instance if (Total Usage:10 
SMS:0
MMS:5
DATACharges:4
Voice:1)

I have done upto displaying the multiline tooltip but problem is coming when i should display one tooltip for individual dropdownvalue it repeats all other tooltip which was displaying the other data as undefined.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,

Shikhar

Answer (score 0):

You can add JavaScript logic in the ClientTemplate of the tooltips, so you can check if the value is undefined or null or whatever and not print anything: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/htmlchart/functionality/clienttemplate/display-html-and-execute-javascript.

```
<ClientTemplate>
    #if (someField != 'undefined') {# #=value# #} else {#  #} #
</ClientTemplate>
```

is a good starting point. Of course, tweak the if statement to fit your needs.